# Linq to XML retrieve single node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<game>
    <name>Space Blaster</name>
    <description></description>
    <version>1</version>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>640</height>
    <c2release>6900</c2release>
</game>
```

It's guaranteed to only have 1 game record in it.  I'd like to retrieve each property value, this is what I've tried:

```
string ArcadeXMLLocation = Settings.GamePergatoryLocation + UserID + "/unzipped/arcade.xml";
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(ArcadeXMLLocation);

var q = (from c in loaded.Descendants("game") select (string)c.Element("name")).SingleOrDefault();
Response.Write(q.name);
```

But I can't seem to take any values like this (intellisense hates it!)  Can someone show me how it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to get the value of the element:

```
string val = doc.Descendants("game")
    .Select(x => x.Element("name").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

As a prerequisite to the above, and so intellisense picks it up,  make sure that you import the `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq` namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all the descendants with the tag "game" 
You just need the FirstOrDefault() to get the only record if it exists.

```
             var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("game")
                select new { Name = c.Element("name").Value
                             Description = c.Element("description").Value
                };

             q.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You query is actually correct (tested and worked for me) for extracting the *value* of the name node - the `(string)` cast that you are doing will extract the value of the name node as string and not give you the node object itself, this is one of the shortcuts built into Linq to Xml. All that is left is to print out the name:

```
Response.Write(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = (from c in loaded.Descendants("game") select (string)c.Element("name")).SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(q);
```

is enough. or to avoid the cast

```
var q = (from c in loaded.Descendants("game") select c.Element("name").Value).SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(q);
```